# Breeze: The array of a complextype is either empty or a string

Tags: breeze

I have an entityType.product with a dataProperty of complexType. Within this complexType I have a property of Ids. When submitting the form either a string is submitted or if I set the property Id of complexType to "isScalar:false" I will get an empty array.

How Con I get the string inside the array?

entityType.product:

```
createInstance: function createInstance(type, data) {
                var metadataStore = this.entityAspect.entityManager.metadataStore;

                return metadataStore.getEntityType(type).createInstance(data);
            }
,addNewMedia: function addNewAttribute(dataContext) {
                var newMedia = this.createInstance('MediaList');
                newMedia.isNew = true;
                this.mediaList.getMediaObjects().push(newMedia);
                return newMedia;
            },
 });
```

complexType.mediaList

```
dataProperties: {
                    /**
                     * @property mainObjectId
                     * @type {String}
                     */
                    mainObjectId: {
                        dataType: DataType.String
                    },
                    /**
                     * @property mediaObjectIds
                     * @type {String}{Array}
                     */
                    mediaObjectIds: {
                        dataType: DataType.Undefined
                    },
```

json:

```
    "dataSource": {
                "structure": {
                    "mainEntity": {
                        "entity": "Product",
                        "relatedEntities": ["MediaObject"]
                    },
                    "mediaObjects": {
                        "entity": "MediaObjects"
                    }
                }
            },
...
 "ngRepeat":"mediaObject in mcData.mainEntity.mediaList.getMediaObjects()",
...
"model": "mcData.mainEntity.mediaList.mediaObjectIds",
```